# Can we make parent class initialization less often than child class'?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I tried to plot sine waves with different frequencies (`f`) and amplitudes (`a`) using class inheritance. But it doesn't seem to me it runs efficiently.
Here is my code where I put common attributes f and a in the parent class and the variable t in the child class.

```
import math
from matplotlib import  pyplot   as plt

class Parent:
    def __init__(self, f, a):
        self.freq = f
        self.ampl = a
        self.color = (f/a/3, (f/a)/2, (f/a)) # some random RGB numbers

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, t, f, a):
        super(Child, self).__init__(f, a)
        self.time = t

    def volt(self):
        omega = 2*math.pi*self.freq
        return self.ampl * math.sin(omega*self.time)

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    for (f,a) in [(0.05,1.5), (0.1,1)]: 
        color = Parent(f, a).color
        time = [i for i in range(50)]
        cl = [Child(x, f, a).volt() for x in time]
        plt.plot(time, cl, color=color)
    plt.xlabel("time")
    plt.ylabel("amplitude")
    plt.title(f"Voltage waveform for different frequencies")
    plt.show()
```

It works. But for every instantiation of `Child(x, f, a)`, it runs `super().__init__` as well, which doesn't change for every variable `x`. I wonder if there is a way to run `Parent` in the outer loop for variable `f, a` and run `Child` in the inner loop for variable `x`.

Comment: I'd question the need of the `Parent` class at all if that is your exact code. I'd also question the need of having a `color` attribute in your class when you don't even seem to be using it. `color = Parent(f, a).color` doesn't count since you could have made that into a separate function, e.g. `color = get_color(f, a)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use static/class variables for Parent class

```
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class Parent:
    freq = None
    ampl = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.color = (self.freq/self.ampl/3, (self.freq/self.ampl)/2, (self.freq/self.ampl)) # some random RGB numbers

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.time = t

    def volt(self):
        omega = 2 * math.pi * self.freq
        return self.ampl * math.sin(omega * self.time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for freq, ampl in [(0.05, 1.5), (0.1, 1)]:
        Parent.freq = freq
        Parent.ampl = ampl
        color = Parent().color
        time = [i for i in range(50)]
        cl = [Child(x).volt() for x in time]
        plt.plot(time, cl, color=color)

    plt.xlabel("time")
    plt.ylabel("amplitude")
    plt.title("Voltage waveform for different frequencies")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I thought about using class static variables. So this does get what I asked for : trade instance variables for a layered and efficient design.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a good reason to use classes like `Parent` and `Child` here. Most attributes on those classes are set but not read, and no attribute needs to be read more than once. Reconsider whether you really need those classes.

My suggested code would be --

```py
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def make_color(freq, ampl):
    return (freq / ampl / 3, freq / ampl / 2, freq / ampl)  # some random RGB numbers

def calc_volt(time, freq, ampl):
    omega = 2 * math.pi * freq
    return ampl * math.sin(omega * time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for freq, ampl in [(0.05, 1.5), (0.1, 1)]:
        color = make_color(freq, ampl)
        time = [i for i in range(50)]
        cl = [calc_volt(x, freq, ampl) for x in time]
        plt.plot(time, cl, color=color)

    plt.xlabel("time")
    plt.ylabel("amplitude")
    plt.title("Voltage waveform for different frequencies")
    plt.show()
```

---

> I agree that for a simple problem like this, you don't need class. But I was using it as an example to explore different designs.

That's OK. Let's go on with classes.

The heaviest part in `Parent.__init__` is the calculation of `color` and `color` is never used on instances of `Child`, therefore the calculation is wasted. I'd suggest making it lazy by `functools.cached_property`.

The related part could be altered into ---

```py
from functools import cached_property

class Parent:
    def __init__(self, f, a):
        self.freq = f
        self.ampl = a

    @cached_property
    def color(self):
        return (f / a / 3, (f / a) / 2, (f / a))  # some random RGB numbers
```

Comment: I agree that for a simple problem like this, you don't need class. But I was using it as an example to explore different designs.

Comment: Invoking super(Child, self).__init_() has function overhead which is not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with class variables, we can eliminate the class inheritance part:

```
import math
from matplotlib import  pyplot   as plt

class Parent:
    freq = None
    ampl = None
    color = None
    def __init__(self, f, a):
        Parent.freq = f
        Parent.ampl = a
        Parent.color = (f/a/3, (f/a)/2, (f/a))

class Child:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.time = t
    def volt(self):
        omega = 2*math.pi*Parent.freq
        return Parent.ampl * math.sin(omega*self.time)

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    for (f,a) in [(0.05,1.5), (0.1,1)]: 
        Parent(f, a) 
        time = [i for i in range(50)]
        cl = [Child(x).volt() for x in time]    
        plt.plot(time, cl, color=Parent.color) 

    plt.xlabel("time")
    plt.ylabel("amplitude")
    plt.title(f"Voltage waveform for different frequencies")
    plt.show()
```